# How to change the view's bounds within UIPresentationController?

Tags: ios, swift

I use subclass of `UIPresentationController` to present some **controller** on the screen. This is how I prepare it:

```
controller.transitioningDelegate = self
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But within **controller** there is a textField, and I have added there observer for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. Is it possible to update view's frame when keyboard appear?

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I need to change the bounds of that view because of keyboard.

Comment: you are asking when keyboard responds your view should get shrinked?

Comment: I think preferredContentSize=CGRectMake(....) will work. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it doesnt change anything:(

Comment: using NSNotificationCenter ,be notified when keyboard up. then try the above

Comment: Yes, I did it like this, but `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView()` is not called then.

Answer (score 4):

`containerView?.setNeedsLayout()` needs to be called after whatever I change.

Comment: Yep, this one works. More precisely, from the partial view controller in question you do: `presentationController?.containerView?.setNeedsLayout()`. Also if you want that animated, call `layoutIfNeeded()` within the keyboard event and it will be nicely animated.

Answer (score 4):

It is relative easy.

First you will need to observe for keyboard changes in your presenter

Listen to notifications `.UIKeyboardWillShow, .UIKeyboardDidShow, .UIKeyboardWillHide, .UIKeyboardDidHide`

I would recommend making a KeyboardObserver class for this with in example a static instance and store the keyboard variables (frame, animation speed etc) in there and add a delegate on that class to inform you on keyboard changes.

You then end up with something like this

```
extension PresentationController: KeyboardManagerDelegate {
    internal func keyboardManager(_ manager: KeyboardManager, action: KeyboardManager.KeyBoardDisplayAction, info: KeyboardManager.Info) {
        guard let containerView = containerView else { return }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: info.animationDuration, delay: 0, options: info.animationOptions, animations: {
            containerView.setNeedsLayout()
            containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Next you will need to override `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`.

Example:

```
override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
    guard let containerView = containerView else {
        return .zero
    }

    let desiredSize = CGSize(width: 540, height: 620)

    let width = min(desiredSize.width, containerView.width)
    let x = round((containerView.width - width) / 2)

    if KeyboardManager.shared.isKeyboardVisible {
        let availableHeight = containerView.height - KeyboardManager.shared.keyboardFrame.height
        let height = availableHeight - 40

        return CGRect(x: x, y: 25, width: width, height: height)
    } else {
        let height = min(desiredSize.height, containerView.height)

        let y = round((containerView.height - height) / 2)

        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

At the end also implement a layout method to update the view

```
override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()

    presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
}
```